# How to implement swt Graphical Compare of 2 text files

Tags: java, compare, swt

Can the eclipse file comparison editor be incorporated into a java swt application?

Or are there any other ways of implementing a graphical comparison of text files, where the differences are highlighted.

Thanks

Comment: The compare editor won't work with just SWT. It would work in an [Eclipse 3.x RCP](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse3RCP/article.html)

Comment: Excellent thanks, i'll have a look